# Android Asynctask for socket scan

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to figure out the best way to loop over all ips in a range(IE 192.168.5.0-192.168.5.255) to find devices that are listening on a given port. The following code is working but I am worried that I wont find all the devices since I have my timeout on my socket too low. The catch 22 is that I want this to be super fast but if I up the timeout it starts to take forever.

```
private class findNetworkDevices extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private String source;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    public findNetworkDevices(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int dest = 0; dest < 255; dest++) {
            String host = "192.168.5." + dest; // TODO: add net address instead of hardcoding
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket();
                s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), 9999), 50);
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "conn:" + s.toString());
                if (s.isConnected()) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "connected " + host);
                    foundDevicesArray.add(host);
                } else {
                    return "failed";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Not found", e);
            }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "end");

            return "All Done!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListView lv = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.foundDevicesList);
            ((BaseAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a small optimization. You should make `Socket s` static outside the loop an reuse it, instead of recreating it every loop. It may be small compared to `s.connect()` but for sure will make your code faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went away from using Async because it took so long. I went with ExecutorService

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);
    String ip = getLocalIpAddress();
    int endIndex = ip.lastIndexOf(".");
    String subnet = ip.substring(0, endIndex);
    for (int dest = 0; dest < 255; dest++) {
        String host = subnet + "." + dest;
        executor.execute(pingRunnable(host));
    }
```

It seems to spawn multiple threads where Async did it in the background but only in one thread.

Comment: Doesn't Android developer documentation recommends to use asynctask for any background op?.. and from there creating the threads to speed up process or doesn't make any difference to call them directly from main thread...